# Express middleware before response is carried out to client

Tags: node.js, express

I need to modify the response data a module sends to the client, as the module uses `res.send` i can't seem to figure out a way for me to modify the data before it's carried out to the client.

Is there any kind of middleware/event that I can use to catch the `res.send` and modify the data before its executed?

I am aware that `router.use` exists but it's called before the `router.post` function and not before the `res.send` is sent to the client. So I need some kind of middleware which is called after the `router.post` function is done but before anything is sent to the client.

Comment: What module are you using that's calling res.send and where is it in your code

Comment: That looks like Express by the syntax, also a quick suggestion, when you are asking questions about Express.js try to use the app keyword instead of the router keyword because that is what most people use when they are using Express.js. It will clear up any misunderstandings of the module that you are using.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well you can override the send function:

```
app.use(function (req, res) {
    var send = res.send;
    res.send = function (body) { // It might be a little tricky here, because send supports a variety of arguments, and you have to make sure you support all of them!
        // Do something with the body...
        send.call(this, body);
    };
});
```

If you want to support more than just calling `send`(like calling `end` method), then you have to override more functions...

You can check [connect-livereload](https://github.com/intesso/connect-livereload/blob/v0.5.2/index.js#L109-159) on how it adds a script to any html output.

Answer (score 5):

One more solution from [here](https://community.apigee.com/questions/12183/usage-of-middleware-after-response-sent.html):

> ```
> expressApp.use(function (req, res, next) {
>     req.on("end", function () {
>         console.log('on request end');
>     });
>     next();
> });
> ```

**Important Note:** To work, this needs to be placed before body parser since it recreates the response object. [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42879692/8430249)

Comment: the link to apigee community seems to be access controlled

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by overriding `res.send`

We override the `res.send` function to capture the response body in our API analytics tool as follows

```
// It will monkey patch the res.send.
// The patch intercepts the send invocation, executes is logic such as atatus.setResponseBody
// then restores the original send function and invokes that to finalize the req/res chain
const resSendInterceptor = (res, send) => (content) => {

    // Set response body in Atatus Analytics
    // Atatus is our API analytics tool
    atatus.setResponseBody(content || '');

    // TODO: You can modify your response body as you wish.

    // Invoke the original send function.
    res.send = send;
    send.apply(this, arguments);

};

// Express Middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {

    // Overrides res.send
    res.send = resSendInterceptor(res, res.send);
    
    return next();
});
```

Answer (score -6):

Your lack of code makes it really hard to answer your question, but you could use something like

```
Express 4.0:
router.use('/path', function (req, res) {
    // Modify req
});
```

`.use` on a route will parse that before continuing on to the actual route so if somebody submitted a form or something, it will hit the `.use` before it goes to the `.post` or `.get`

Or you can do

```
Express 4.0:
app.use(function (req, res) {
    // Modify Req
    if (req.body.hasOwnProperty('some_form_name')) {
       // Do Somthing
    }
});
```

Which is the same thing, but it will be called before every request for every route.

Not sure if this answers your question but I think this might be what you're looking for?

Comment: This is what I looked at, but this is for requests I need something that catches the res.send before it's sent out to the user. Will update my question to clarify.

Comment: Please mention about response,  as it is not about request