# run express middleware before returning response

Tags: node.js, express

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885425/express-middleware-before-response-is-carried-out-to-client) and its answer, but it seems like a hack and I would think twice before putting something like this on a production application. Is there any way to run some business code at the end of a request, such as cleaning up resources, using express middleware and without hacks?

Currently I'm using [node's response-finish event](https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.2/docs/api/http.html#http_event_finish) to run this logic, but it runs after the response has been sent to the client, and occasionally causes conflicts with subsequent requests that need to work on these resources. I would like to find a way to run my logic before returning the response to the client.

Comment: Could you provide more details on what you're trying to do at the end of the request?

Comment: Just an observation. The clean-up work that you want to do might take time, and the response to the client might therefore need to wait. Maybe not a desirable behaviour...

Comment: Well we create an exclusive lock on the resource being worked on for the duration of the request, and that lock needs to be released before the client can continue. Releasing the lock asynchronously is causing undesirable race condition behavior.