# node.js ~ express req.on('end') triggers but not req.on('data')

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Using body parser either

> - application/x-www-form-urlencoded body parser

or

> - json body parser

Yields the same results.

This is how I'm calling the API

`$.ajax({ type:'post', url:'/api/order', headers: { 'GreatestHits': 'SteveMillerBand' }, data: { 'the': 'greatest' } });`

**Why isn't `.on('data')` triggering**? **Isn't `body` simply the `data` object of the request, pretty much**?  I am seeing the form data logging to the console.  I can also direct the post to `http://httpbin.org/post` to prove the point.
I can only believe the Express is the real c@ blocker.  If that is not it then I at a loss.

```
// this is the code being called by the $.ajax()
app.use(function (req, res) {
    console.log("app.use req.data", req.data);
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log("req.use on data");
    }).on('end', function () {
        console.log("app.use on end");
    });
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

On the `$.ajax()` post each of the following models, based on the above code, results as shown:

`app.use(callback() {} )`

> - has req.body
> - does not have req.data (undefined)
>
>   - will NOT trigger .on('data');
>   - will NOT trigger .on('end');

.

`app.post(callback() {} )`

> - will not even be called unless a route string is included.

.
`app.post('route', callback() {} )`

> - has `req.body`
> - does not have `req.data` (undefined)
>
>   - will NOT trigger `.on('data');`
>   - will NOT trigger `.on('end');`

.

`app.use('route', callback() {} )`

> - has `req.body`
> - does not have `req.data` (undefined)
>
>   - will NOT trigger `.on('data');`
>   - will trigger `.on('end');`

Comment: `app.use` seems odd here, that's really more for middleware vs. route handling.  Generally for routes you can use `.use` to pull in something that knows how to handle specific routes.  See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Than you.  But I believe the app.use() is required so we have re object to put the emitter req.on() pointing to the callback.  This is taken from and based on a very typical code snips all over the internet.

Comment: Does Request even have an `on` method? [It's doesn't seem to be documented](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) and doesn't document any events. In fact, the only event I see listed on that entire page is Application's `mount`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that might be a good catch.  I didn't thank abut that.  And when I inspect req. I don't see it.  But I do see this code in a lot of places on the internet claiming to do what I'm attempting.  So where could I be off?  Versions of node maybe?

Comment: for instance from nodejs.org https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/

Comment: If .on() is not part of req then shouldn't I see seeing the exception ".on() is not a function"?

Comment: @user2367083: [Express's Request](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) != [Node's IncomingMessage](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage).

Comment: Ok. So how do I get body at Express's level?

Comment: @user2367083: See the Express documentation linked above: [`req.body`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body) (note the need for middleware, like [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser)).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Thanks for sticking with me.  All alone I've had body-parser & have been down this road for a while over `req.body` for quite a while now.  For instance  is I `console.log(req.body)`  All that is logged is `{}` which suggest I've got an empty body object.  But I'm what I'm posting isn't empty.  Or maybe I'm not understanding what body in Express really is.

Comment: @user2367083: Have you worked through the [examples on body-parser's npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#examples)?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Those are the only examples I've seen that buts the parser in a variable.  I'm still playing with that.  But do this for me? I am having trouble with what I think I'm sending as a body.  In a post Isn't body just the data object of the post request?  Can you add a 'body' to this ajax? $.ajax({ type:'post', url:'/api/order', headers: { 'GreatestHits': 'SteveMillerBand' }, .... })

Comment: fyi.  my "body" is `... ,data: { 'the': 'greatest' }`

Comment: If `body-parser` is still active, it will read and exhaust the request stream, so `data` will never trigger for you (because there won't be any more data to read). Also: show how you configured `body-parser`.

Comment: @robertklep neither `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var bParser = bodyParser.json();` nor `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var bParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })` make a difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment thread is too long already to continue adding to it.  Not knowing what better I can do I'm posting this as an answer to continue the conversation.

This code triggers .on('end')

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("app.use req.data", req.body);
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log("req.use on data");
    }).on('end', function () {
        console.log("app.use on end");
    });
    next();
});
```

This is the call to the above;

```
$.ajax({ type:'post', url:'/api/order', headers: { 'GreatestHits': 'SteveMillerBand' }, data: { 'the': 'greatest' } });
```

**Why isn't `.on('data')` triggering?**  I am seeing the form data logging to the console.

Also. If the data segment is know as `req.body` then why isn't it `req.on('body')`?

Because, I find out, that `Body-Parser.js` complete consumes the `response` object it receives from `Node.js` & it re-writes it thereby re-creating `response` as an object expectionally different from the `node.js` `response` object.