# Handling NodeJS streaming values before sending response to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pipe, streaming

How can I parse the results from `res` before sending the `res` to the client?

As I understand, the results from `request(url)` will make a request to another server and stream the response data to the 2nd `.pipe()`. However, I would like to parse the response BEFORE sending the response to the client. Specifically, I want to check if the header from the response contains a specific key/value pair and also analyze the response body (`res.body`). Depending on the data in the `body` and/or `header`, I would like to return the appropriate HTTP code and/or response body

```
app.use("/path", (req, res) => {
  const url = `localhost:8000`;
  const stream = intoStream(req.body.toString());
  stream.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Accepted answer here suggests to override the send function which might give you an idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885425/express-middleware-before-response-is-carried-out-to-client

Comment: does `intoStream` turn a string into a Readable stream?

Comment: @richytong First time looking at this code but I believe it does. https://www.npmjs.com/package/into-stream

Comment: `req` is already a stream.... why read the whole thing, just to convert it back to a stream?  And, I don't know what framework you're using to get the body there, but just use that directly since you need to inspect it.

Comment: is `req.body` JSON?

Comment: ^ I meant `res.body`